# Загрузка сцены из Bundle

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите почему мой сцена не добавляется в build list - что не так сделал?

```
public IEnumerator LoadSceneBundle()
        {
            using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url, 4))
            {
                yield return www;
                if (www.error != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("WWW donwload had an error : " + url + " " + www.error);
                    //Debug.Log("");
                }
                var ab = www.assetBundle;
                Debug.Log(www.assetBundle);
                var original = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
                var newSettings = new EditorBuildSettingsScene[original.Length + 1];
                System.Array.Copy(original, newSettings, original.Length);
                var sceneToAdd = new EditorBuildSettingsScene(Application.dataPath + "Level1.unity", true);
                newSettings[newSettings.Length - 1] = sceneToAdd;
                EditorBuildSettings.scenes = newSettings;
                Application.LoadLevel("Level1");
                ab.Unload(false);
            }
        }
```

Получаю ошибку :

```
TypeLoadException : A type load exception has occurred
```

Comment: В какой строчке, еще бы подробнее про ошибку

Comment: @Xumera_hZ ошибка везде , где есть EditorBuildSettings

Comment: @Xumera_hZ так я пытаюсь добавить сцену в готовую игры - типо DLC

Comment: тебя слово Editor не смущает? он не работает в playmode и тем более в билде, его можно использовать только в EditorMode

Comment: @Xumera_hZ проще сказать,что нельзя загрузить свой уровень?

Comment: @Sector32 проще сказать, что загружать свой уровень в playmode или в билде можно, только по-другому http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/915566/load-scene-from-asset-bundle-1.html